# Hidden materials issue

Tags: materials, unity

In my model, I have 4 objects that share 2 different materials.
However, when exporting to Unity, the first object has the correct 2 materials, the second object has 3 materials, third object has 4 materials etc.

However, only 2 materials show up in Blender. It managed to have it working before, so there must be something I did that causes the hidden materials to show up.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are these materials different, or are they simply copies of the original two?

Comment: If you upload the .blend to PasteAll.org and paste the link here I'm sure someone will be able to diagnose the issue and have an answer posted soon after.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same exact issue. The entire mesh is only using a single material in blender, but when importing into Unity, unity keeps automatically adding additional material to the material array of the mesh.